# Changing elements in a tuple converted to list in Python

Tags: python, list, replace, tuples

In a Python code, I have a list of tuples like that:

```
file1 = [[('a', -1), ('b', -1), ('c', -1)], [('a', -1), ('b', -1), ('c', 0)], [('a', -1), ('b', -1), ('c', 1)], [('a', 0), ('b', -1), ('c', 1)]]
```

It is a list with 51 items. I have to change all of the '-1' for '0', and as long as I change it, I have to create a new tuple for each change. For example: the first tuple: `[('a', -1), ('b', -1), ('c', -1)]` should generate three different tuples like:
`(1) [('a', 0), ('b', -1), ('c', -1)], [('a', -1), ('b', 0), ('c', -1)] and (3) [('a', -1), ('b', -1), ('c', 0)]`.

I tried by converting all tuples into lists but it is not working. I tried also

```
for i in file1:
    i = list(i)
    for j in i:
        j = list(j)
        if j[1] == -1:
            j = (j[0],0)
            file2.append(i)
```

How this could be solved? It is not changing any item.

Comment: And by extension the second list `[('a', -1), ('b', -1), ('c', 0)]` should give `[('a', 0), ('b', -1), ('c', 0)]` and `[('a', -1), ('b', 0), ('c', 0)]`?

Comment: Yes, this one has only two '-1' values. So it gives only two different tuples.

Comment: Do you want all the results in a flat list? Or do you want the 3 results from the first list in a list of their own, the two results of the second list in another list, etc?

Comment: Flat list, This was only a sample, the entire list has 51 tuples. The resulting list should have probably much more than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any changes, because each time you append `i`. And you're also iterating over the sublist items, but don't actually store the whole new changed sublist anywhere. Instead, when you iterate over the items of the sublist and encounter a -1, create a copy of the sublist, change the value to 0 at that index and append this new copy to the result.

```
file1 = [[('a', -1), ('b', -1), ('c', -1)], [('a', -1), ('b', -1), ('c', 0)], [('a', -1), ('b', -1), ('c', 1)], [('a', 0), ('b', -1), ('c', 1)]]

file2 = []
for items in file1:
    for i, (_, value) in enumerate(items):
        if value == -1:
            tmp = items.copy()
            tmp[i] = (tmp[i][0], 0)
            file2.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Thank you! I just had to remove the lines with "if not idx" and the following line. The tuples with no instances of "-1" should not be added to file2.

Comment: @ChrSld I've amended the answer, which also simplifies the code somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

```
from copy import deepcopy

# somewhere to save results
file2 = []

# loop the outer list
for inner_list in file1:

  # save the original (or remove, if not needed)
  file2.append(inner_list)

  # loop the individual tuples
  for i, t in enumerate(inner_list):

    # find any -1s
    if t[1] == -1:

      # save the list, again
      file2.append(deepcopy(inner_list))

      # replace the required tuple
      file2[-1][i] = tuple([t[0], 0])
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to append `inner_list` if it contains any -1. Also, there is no need for a deepcopy, a simple copy will suffice.